# Rails4: How to delete the image and record in DB at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

How can I delete a record in DB at the same time when I destroy an image?
A record still remain in DB after submitting with tick `<%= p.check_box :_destroy %>` in _article_form.html.erb although the image is deleted.

**Updated**
What I did was as followings;
1. I uploaded 3 files. `p.object.id` are 1, 2 and 3, for example. It worked.
2. I ticked 1 file (`p.object.id` is 1) for destroy and submitted. It worked. Both the record in DB and the image were deleted. The rest of images (2 files) are displayed.
3. I ticked 1 file (`p.object.id` is 2) for destroy and submitted. It doesn't work. The record in DB and the image (`p.object.id` is 2) was deleted, but new record (`p.object.id` is **4**) was inserted in DB for some reason...

\uploaders\image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    .
    .
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
    .
    .
```

\models\article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    .
    .
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
    validate :check_for_at_least_image
    .
    .
    def build_images
      (3 - self.photos.size).times {self.photos.build}
    end

    def check_for_at_least_image
      errors.add(:image, "select at least one") if self.photos.size <= 0
    end

end
```

\models\photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

\controller\articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

.
.
  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.build_images
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy #This is used for destroying @article, NOT photo
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:content, :category_id, photos_attributes: [:id, :article_id, :image, :image_cache, :_destroy])
    end

.
.
end
```

\view\shared\ _article_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :article_id %>
      <div class="photo">
      <% if p.object.image and p.object.image.file %>
        <%= image_tag p.object.image.thumb.url %>
        <%= p.hidden_field :image_cache if p.object.image_cache %>
        <label><%= p.check_box :_destroy %>delete</label> #tick this check box
      <% end %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "enter..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove the the data from both db and view ,then i recommend this way...without using `accept_nested_attributes_for` which will work only after saving the parent object and will delete the child using `_destroy` attribute being set as true/1.

**1. give your elements a unique id by passing object.id

2. use this object.id to select the element and remove it using js.erb with a remote call/ajax on same page on success**

**==========first method(without accept_nested_attributes-for)======================

---------using remote method call(without setting  _destroy)----------------**

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :article_id %>
      ##here i added id field which i need to recognize using id 
      <div class="photo" id="photo_<%= p.id %>">
      <% if p.object.image and p.object.image.file %>
        <%= image_tag p.object.image.thumb.url %>
        <%= p.hidden_field :image_cache if p.object.image_cache %>
        ##instead of checkbox,use link_to
        ##<label><%= p.check_box :_destroy %>delete</label> #tick this check box
         <%= link_to "Delete", article_path(p),{:method => :delete,:remote=>true%>
        </td>
      <% end %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "enter..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**in articles_controller.rb**

```
  def destroy
  ##first remove from db and then from view using id passed 
   @article=Artice.find params[:id]
    @audio.destroy
          respond_to do |format|
           format.js 
         end
  end
```

**in destroy.js.erb**

```
##delete the image from your view using p.id with a slideup animation(if needed)
$("#photo_<%= params[:id] %").slideUp("slow", function() { $('#photo_<%= params[:id]%>').remove();});
```

**==========second method(using accept nested attribute for)==========================

---------using jquery to delete image and marking object to destruction by setting _destroy to 1(using _destroy by setting it to 1)-------**

**in your view**

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :article_id %>
      <div class="photo">
      <% if p.object.image and p.object.image.file %>
        <%= image_tag p.object.image.thumb.url %>
        <%= p.hidden_field :image_cache if p.object.image_cache %>
        ##on click of checkbox,set _destroy to 1,which will get deleted by parent
        ##when parent is updated/saved
        <label><%= p.check_box :_destroy :class => 'delete_member', :p_id => p.id %>
          delete</label> #tick this check box

        </td>
      <% end %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "enter..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**your jquery**

```
  $('.delete_member').click(function(){
        //remove div from screen using class photo
        $(this).closest('.photo').remove();
         //get relevant id to remove/mark as delete
         id =jQuery(this).attr('p_id');
         //remove/mark the nested model/record as ready for deletion for rails by adding true/1     value
         $("input[p_id="+id+"]").attr('value',1);
```

So after setting _destroy to 1,the record will also gets removed by rails as we have marked it for destruction using _destroy attribute

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Milind. I updated my question and sources. The first time I ticked and submitted, it worked as I updated. When I tried to delete the next image, it failed. So I suppose these codes are basically correct. Do you have any thought without using ajax and jquery?

Comment: @SamuraiBlue...as we are using js to set the `value` to 1 which gets autodestroyed...you need to check the js...check if its setting the value to 1 of the selected element...use `console.log(p_id)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried, but I couldn't. I haven't used Ajax and jQuery before. So I will try your code again after learning Ajax and jQuery for Rails.

Answer (score 0):

`dependent: :destroy` should work if you destroy an article it should destroy the photos. If that's buggy, you can always create a callback "`before_destroy`" or "`after_destroy`".

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user2012677. I updated my question and sources. The first time I ticked and submitted, it worked as I updated. When I tried to delete the next image, it failed. So I suppose these codes are basically correct. Do you have any thought without using `before_destroy` or `after_destroy`? Or it would be appreciated if you could show me the code using `before_destroy` or `after_destroy` for my case.

Answer (score 0):

you could try rename `_destroy` to `remove_file` or `remove_<mounted-point>`

if you want to remove the file manually, you can call `remove_<mounted-point>!`, then save the object (or do it in callback).

```
photo.remove_<mounted-point>!
photo.save
```

Comment: thank you for your advise. Although I renamed `_destroy` to `remove_image`, it didn't work. The image is still displayed.

Comment: are you sure that carrierwave doesn't delete file after destroying `Photo` records? do you mount your file uploader to :image field?

Comment: I updated `\photo.rb`. Although it has `mount_uploader :image ImageUploader`, it doesn't delete file and `Photo` record.